# getting exception from windows app in release mode after running it successfully 10 hours , how detected what went wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling

I have Qt app that runs on my desktop and collecting data from the internet.
i noticed that when i run it in release mode after 10 / 15 hours running great it throws
windows exception , the one that ask to send the error to microsoft .
i tried to get he error file but what i got is xml with all my app dll's it using .
that looks like this : how do i even start to find out what the cause of the exception ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="MyTestApp.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="libeay32.dll" SIZE="1099776" CHECKSUM="0x50839BDD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0d" FILE_DESCRIPTION="OpenSSL Shared Library" COMPANY_NAME="The OpenSSL Project, http://www.openssl.org/" PRODUCT_NAME="The OpenSSL Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0d" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="libeay32.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="libeay32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1998-2005 The OpenSSL Project. Copyright © 1995-1998 Eric A. Young, Tim J. Hudson. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x11B5DA" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:12" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:12" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="libssl32.dll" SIZE="237056" CHECKSUM="0x7C9A2CE9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0d" FILE_DESCRIPTION="OpenSSL Shared Library" COMPANY_NAME="The OpenSSL Project, http://www.openssl.org/" PRODUCT_NAME="The OpenSSL Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0d" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ssleay32.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="ssleay32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1998-2005 The OpenSSL Project. Copyright © 1995-1998 Eric A. Young, Tim J. Hudson. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x40587" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:25" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="MyTestApp.exe" SIZE="764416" CHECKSUM="0x7E7F4BD6" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xC251C" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="02/23/2012 11:58:10" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/23/2012 11:58:10" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtCore4.dll" SIZE="2518528" CHECKSUM="0xAB9AF26C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtCore4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x26AA8A" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:45:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:45:51" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtGui4.dll" SIZE="8350208" CHECKSUM="0xBA76BC4F" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtGui4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x803F75" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:58:59" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:58:59" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtNetwork4.dll" SIZE="1006080" CHECKSUM="0x2B31F4A6" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtNetwork4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xF9DD3" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:47:11" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:47:11" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtSql4.dll" SIZE="194560" CHECKSUM="0xE21A4335" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtSql4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3183A" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:47:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:47:20" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtWebKit4.dll" SIZE="12747264" CHECKSUM="0x80601845" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.9.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.9.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.9.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtWebKit4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xC2BEDF" LINKER_VERSION="0x4005A" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.9.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.9.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 08:59:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 08:59:06" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="QtXml4.dll" SIZE="341504" CHECKSUM="0x6B324163" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="QtXml4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x5D4B5" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:46:12" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 05:46:12" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ssleay32.dll" SIZE="237056" CHECKSUM="0x7C9A2CE9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0d" FILE_DESCRIPTION="OpenSSL Shared Library" COMPANY_NAME="The OpenSSL Project, http://www.openssl.org/" PRODUCT_NAME="The OpenSSL Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0d" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ssleay32.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="ssleay32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1998-2005 The OpenSSL Project. Copyright © 1995-1998 Eric A. Young, Tim J. Hudson. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x40587" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.4" LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/19/2011 06:05:25" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="imageformats\qgif4.dll" SIZE="27136" CHECKSUM="0xB301057E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="qgif4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x154ED" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:04:56" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:04:56" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="imageformats\qico4.dll" SIZE="29184" CHECKSUM="0x5CF349C7" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="qico4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x10E8B" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:05:22" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:05:22" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="imageformats\qjpeg4.dll" SIZE="197632" CHECKSUM="0x3B21342B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="qjpeg4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x38B4B" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:04:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/08/2011 09:04:51" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="sqldrivers\qsqlite4.dll" SIZE="546304" CHECKSUM="0x2905DF55" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="C++ application development framework." COMPANY_NAME="Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)" PRODUCT_NAME="Qt4" FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="qsqlite4.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x9356B" LINKER_VERSION="0x40050" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.8.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.8.0.0" LINK_DATE="02/06/2012 10:41:55" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/06/2012 10:41:55" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="989696" CHECKSUM="0x2D998938" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.090321-1317)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFE572" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Comment: One suggestion is to attach a debugger like windbg and let the app run. The debugger will break whenever the exception is thrown, then you can inspect the callstack.

Comment: Adding a debug log might help as well, just a text file that is written to at different parts of your functions. That way you can at least see where it was when it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching with a debugger is a good idea.

Also, when you get the Microsoft dialog, you can click on the "technical information" link and (with a little clicking) figure out where it dumped the core files.  You want the heap dump, which I think it stores with .hdmp.  Copy that somewhere, rename to .dmp, and it's a normal dump file.  You can open it with Visual Studio (for example) or WinDBG, and it'll show you where the crash occurred.

It's sometimes easy to get information from a dump, sometimes not, depending on what caused the crash.

Also, you'll need the symbols (.pdb file), or else this won't tell you anything.  If you compiled from source, you'll have them if you didn't erase them.  If you didn't compile from source, see if you can get them from where you got the source.